# How to create a hidden folder in Android SD card and Push content to it

Tags: java, android, performance, storage, android-sdcard

How can I created a hidden folder in the android SD card and copy all the content of another normal folder to into this hidden folder.

ie.

```
< I have this folder already >
```

FOLDER 1  = /sd/content_folder (here is all my files, images, videos, html...)

```
<Folder to be created>
```

FOLDER 2 = /sd/.special_folder

Now after the FOLDER 2 is created we need to copy all the content from FOLDER 1 into the folder 2 programmatically in android

FOLDER 2, must be a hidden folder ad .special_folder

Is this possible guys, if so, can you advice me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ADB to push the content

```
adb push dir1 dir2
```

Or for advanced use, and more control use SHELL

adb shell >

```
shell: cp -R dir1 dir2/  # copy dir1 into dir2 including subdirectries
```

https://www-xray.ast.cam.ac.uk/~jss/lecture/computing/notes/out/commands_basic/